# How to iterate over a string of varying length, replacing different abbreviations with their full text. All abbreviations separated by a semicolon

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

My problem is this; I have a field in a table that contains values like this:

```
NP

NP;MC;PE

MC;AB;AT;MI;TC;WM

OS

OG
```

I want to convert these abbreviations to their full name. i.e. NP becomes Nuclear Power, OG becomes Oil and Gas, MI becomes Military etc.

My desired output would be:

```
Nuclear Power
Nuclear Power;Military;Pesticides
```

and so on.

I'm creating this as a function. I got it working for just the one abbreviation and then the same for two. However my issue is that I may have 5 abbreviations or 7. I know my current approach is dreadful but cannot figure out how to loop it in the right way.

**Please note:** I've shortened the list of abbreviations for StackOverflow but there's 25 in total.

**Please further note:** I did the function bottom up (I don't know why) and got the two value and single value working. I've removed anything I did for values over 3 as nothing I did worked.

```
ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[get_str_full] 
(
    -- Add the parameters for the function here
    @str_input VARCHAR(250)
)
RETURNS VARCHAR(250)
AS
BEGIN
    -- Declare the return variable here
    DECLARE @Result VARCHAR(250)
    DECLARE @TEMPSTRING VARCHAR(250) 
    DECLARE @TEMPSTRING_RIGHT AS VARCHAR(250)
--  DECLARE @PI_COUNT BIGINT
    DECLARE @COUNTER INT
    DECLARE @TOTAL_VALS BIGINT
    DECLARE @STRING_ST VARCHAR(250)
    DECLARE @POS_STR BIGINT
    DECLARE @REMAINING_STR VARCHAR(250)

    -- Used for easy loop skips
    DECLARE @LEFTSKIP AS BIGINT             
    SET @LEFTSKIP = 1
    
    SET @Result = @str_input
    SET @STRING_ST = @Result
    SET @COUNTER = (LEN(@Result) - LEN(REPLACE(@Result,';',''))) + 1
    SET @TOTAL_VALS = (LEN(@Result) - LEN(REPLACE(@Result,';',''))) + 1

    -- If the string has a semicolon then there's more than one PI value
    IF CHARINDEX(';', @Result) > 0
    BEGIN       
        WHILE @COUNTER > 0
        BEGIN
            IF @TOTAL_VALS >= 3 -- If counter is more than 2 then there's three or more 
                BEGIN
                    DECLARE @TEMP_VAL BIGINT
                    SET @TEMP_VAL = 5
                END             
            ELSE IF @TOTAL_VALS = 2-- Theres 2 
                BEGIN
                    -- Do left two chars first
                    IF @LEFTSKIP = 1
                        BEGIN
                                SET @TEMPSTRING = LEFT(@Result, 2)                                                              
                                SELECT @TEMPSTRING = CASE @TEMPSTRING
                                    WHEN 'MC' THEN 'Military Contracting'
                                    WHEN 'NP' THEN 'Nuclear'
                                    WHEN 'OG' THEN 'Oil & Gas'
                                    WHEN 'OS' THEN 'Oil Sands'
                                    WHEN 'PM' THEN 'Palm Oil'
                                    WHEN 'PE' THEN 'Pesticides'
                                    ELSE @TEMPSTRING
                                END
                            SET @LEFTSKIP = 2
                        END
                    ELSE IF @LEFTSKIP = 2       
                            BEGIN                               
                                SET @TEMPSTRING_RIGHT = RIGHT(@Result, 2)                                                               
                                SELECT @TEMPSTRING_RIGHT = CASE @TEMPSTRING_RIGHT
                                    WHEN 'MC' THEN 'Military Contracting'
                                    WHEN 'NP' THEN 'Nuclear'
                                    WHEN 'OG' THEN 'Oil & Gas'
                                    WHEN 'OS' THEN 'Oil Sands'
                                    WHEN 'PM' THEN 'Palm Oil'
                                    WHEN 'PE' THEN 'Pesticides'
                                    ELSE @TEMPSTRING_RIGHT
                                END
                        END
                END         
            SET @COUNTER = @COUNTER - 1
        END
        SET @Result = CONCAT(@TEMPSTRING,';', @TEMPSTRING_RIGHT)
    END
    ELSE
    BEGIN
        SET @Result = REPLACE(@Result, 'MC', 'Military Contracting')
        SET @Result = REPLACE(@RESULT, 'NP', 'Nuclear Power')
        SET @Result = REPLACE(@Result, 'OG', 'Oil & Gas')
        SET @Result = REPLACE(@Result, 'OS', 'Oil Sands')
        SET @Result = REPLACE(@Result, 'PM', 'Palm Oil')
        SET @Result = REPLACE(@Result, 'PE', 'Pesticides')
    END
       
    -- Return the result of the function
    RETURN @Result
END
```

Comment: Have considered using a suitable [string splitter](https://web.archive.org/web/20210323200038/https://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/tally-oh-an-improved-sql-8k-%E2%80%9Ccsv-splitter%E2%80%9D-function) and joining to a lookup table to translate abbreviations to text? From [`String_Split`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/string-split-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15): "The output rows might be in any order. The order is _not_ guaranteed to match the order of the substrings in the input string."

Comment: Are the abbreviations _always_ two characters? Otherwise you have the possibility of overlapping abbreviations, e.g. `'DOS'` and `'OS'`. That makes the order of replacements important: do the longest first.

Comment: I guess simple question is: why are you storing multiple pieces of info in a single column

Answer (score 1):

First for some easily consumable sample data:

```
DECLARE @tranlation TABLE(tCode VARCHAR(10), tString VARCHAR(40));
DECLARE @t TABLE(String VARCHAR(1000));
INSERT  @t VALUES('PE;N'),('NP'),('NP;MC;PE;XX')
INSERT  @tranlation VALUES ('N','Nukes'),('NP','Nuclear Power'),('MC','Military'),
                           ('PE','Pesticides');
```

Note my updated sample data which includes "XX", which has no match , and an "N" for "Nukes" which would wreck any solution which leverages REPLACE. If you are on SQL 2016+ you can use [STRING_SPLIT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/string-split-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) and [STRING_AGG](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/string-agg-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15).

```
SELECT
  OldString = t.String,
  NewString = STRING_AGG(ISNULL(tx.tString,items.[value]),';')
FROM        @t                         AS t
OUTER APPLY STRING_SPLIT(t.String,';') AS items
LEFT JOIN   @tranlation                AS tx
  ON        items.[value] = tx.tCode
GROUP BY    t.String ;
```

**Returns:**

```
OldString         NewString
----------------- -------------------------------------------
NP                Nuclear Power
NP;MC;PE;XX       Nuclear Power;Military;Pesticides;XX
PE;N              Pesticides;Nukes
```

Answer (score 1):

You should really fix your table design so that you do not store multiple pieces of info in one column.

**If you would like it as a function, I would strongly recommend an inline Table-Valued function rather than a scalar function.**

If you have SQL Server version 2017+ you can use `STRING_SPLIT` and `STRING_AGG` for this.

```sql
CREATE OR ALTER FUNCTION GetFullStr
    ( @str varchar(250) )
RETURNS TABLE
AS RETURN
(
    SELECT STRING_AGG(ISNULL(v.FullStr, s.value), ';') result
    FROM STRING_SPLIT(@str, ';') s
    LEFT JOIN (VALUES
        ('MC', 'Military Contracting'),
        ('NP', 'Nuclear'),
        ('OG', 'Oil & Gas'),
        ('OS', 'Oil Sands'),
        ('PM', 'Palm Oil'),
        ('PE', 'Pesticides')
    ) v(Abbr, FullStr) ON v.Abbr = s.value
);

GO
```

You can, and should, replace the `VALUES` with a real table.

On 2016 you would need `FOR XML PATH` instead of `STRING_AGG`:

```sql
CREATE OR ALTER FUNCTION GetFullStr
    ( @str varchar(250) )
RETURNS TABLE
AS RETURN
(
    SELECT STUFF(
        (SELECT ';' + ISNULL(v.FullStr, s.value)
        FROM STRING_SPLIT(@str, ';') s
        LEFT JOIN (VALUES
            ('MC', 'Military Contracting'),
            ('NP', 'Nuclear'),
            ('OG', 'Oil & Gas'),
            ('OS', 'Oil Sands'),
            ('PM', 'Palm Oil'),
            ('PE', 'Pesticides')
        ) v(Abbr, FullStr) ON v.Abbr = s.value
        FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
        ).value('text()[1]','varchar(2500)'),
      , 1, 1, '')
);

GO
```

You use it like this:

```sql
SELECT s.result AS FullStr
FROM table
OUTER APPLY GetFullStr(value) AS s;
-- alternatively
SELECT (SELECT * FROM GetFullStr(value)) AS FullStr
FROM table;
```

Comment: I beat you to it by 5 minutes. But we apparently think a like so +1 for that.

Answer (score 0):

You could assign your abbreviation mappings to a `TABLE` variable and then use that for your `REPLACE`.  You could build this into a function, then pass your string values in.

The test below returns `Military:Nuclear Power:XX`.

```
declare @mapping table (abbrev varchar(50), fullname varchar(100))

insert into @mapping(abbrev, fullname)
values ('NP','Nuclear Power'),
       ('MC','Military')

declare @testString varchar(100), @newString varchar(100)

set @teststring = 'MC:NP:XX'
set @newString = @testString

SELECT @newString = REPLACE(@newString, abbrev, fullname) FROM @mapping
select @newString
```

Comment: Careful! Note what happens when you add this row to your mapping table: `('N','Nukes')`; you get: *Military:Nukesuclear Power:XX* when you should get *Military;Nuclear Power;XX*